# Prove that there exists a point where $f(x) = g(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f, g : [0, 1] → [0,∞)$ be continuous functions satisfying
> $\sup_{0≤x≤1} f(x) = \sup_{0≤x≤1} g(x)$. Prove that there exists $x_0∈[0, 1]$ such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$.

I know I need to use the IVP as well as take $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. However, I am not sure where to go after this.

Comment: Consider the points $x_1, x_2$ where $f$ resp. $g$ attain their supremum. What can you say about $h(x_1)$ and $h(x_2)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Here's some intuition for what's happening. Of course, if $f(0) = g(0)$, then we're done. Otherwise, we have $f(0) < g(0)$ or $g(0) < f(0)$. Consider the first case: to begin with, $f(x) < g(x)$. However, at some point, the function $f$ must attain its supremum (why?).

Draw example graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and convince your self that the graph $y = g(x)$ must intersect the graph $y = f(x)$ at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f,g$ are continous on the compact $\left [0;1 \right ]$,there exists $a,b \in \left [0;1 \right ]$  such that $$f(a)=g(b)=\sup_{x\in \left [0;1 \right ]} f(x)=\sup_{x\in \left [0;1 \right ]} g(x)$$
If $a=b$ we are done, if not $$h(a)\geq 0; h(b)\leq 0$$
So IVT applies $\cdots$

Comment: many thanks, How do you show that h(a) and H(b) are larger than/smaller than 0?